# If i have a single entry Cyprus Visa is it possible to enter Romania on this visa?

Tags: visas, romania, cyprus

I was applying for a Romanian visa and on the application there was a list of statements and one of them says "if you have a visa from cyprus or bulgaria or croatia" i have a single entry cyprus visa and i clicked on that option and it said at the bottom "visa for romania is not needed if one of these applies" and the next button to continue was removed, so from everything i have read im allowed to enter Romania with this SINGLE entry cyprus visa, i want to clarify if i missed anything

Comment: For completeness, what is your proposed itinerary - do you plan to visit Cyprus as well as Romania?

Comment: The plan is to visit cyprus and romania, from what i saw entering romania then entering cyrpus as the final destination is possible with a single entry cyprus visa

Answer (score 2):

TIMATIC (the database that airlines use for documentation) state :

> ### Romania - Destination Visa
>
> #### Visa Exemptions
>
> Passengers with a “C" visa issued by Bulgaria or Cyprus, valid for the period of intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> The maximum stay is granted within 180 days.

A single entry visa becomes invalid as soon as you have used up that entry and leave the country.

You can do the routing Romania → Cyprus without issue and without visa

Comment: Thank you very much, this clarification really helped, i will be doing a trip to romania for a few days and then to cyprus as the last destination of my holiday with a single entry Cyprus visa, have a nice day :)

Answer (score -5):

Romania is not a part of the Schengen Area, and Cyprus is not a member of the European Union's (EU) Schengen Zone either. Therefore, a visa issued by Cyprus, even if it is a single-entry visa, does not grant you entry into Romania.
If you plan to visit Romania, You may need to apply for a separate visa for Romania.

Comment: This answer is wrong. See https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040